# xIP vs xSP vs xBP: How to choose the target?

Tags: exploit, register, rop

We have 32bit & 64bit binaries, and in ROP (Return Oriented Programming), we sometimes target `RSP`/`ESP`, sometimes `RIP`/`EIP`, (maybe) sometimes `RBP`/`EBP` (I'm new to this, haven't seen `RBP` used yet). In ROP Emporium's [ret2win](https://ropemporium.com/challenge/ret2win.html) challenge, I hit (with the target address) `EIP` on the 32bit binary, but `RSP` on the 64bit since I couldn't get my payload to hit `RIP`.

How do we choose which of the 3 registers to target when making a ROP chain/gadget?